# How to use google play services in a Libgdx application activity?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

**i'm using google play services in my android libgdx game**

**what i want to implement is** using the `AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication` activity for initializing both the game and the `GoogleApiClient` object

**the problem i faced is** when i want to call the `GoogleApiClient.Builder.enableAutoManage();` method of the `` i must pass a `FragmentActivity` which isn't a super class of the `AndroidApplication` class of libgdx

Answer (score 0):

the problem solved by **using**

`AndroidLauncher extends AndroidFragmentApplication`

**instead of**

`AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication`